# Invert / recreate chart issue in Highcharts 3.0

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I'm working with an issue of missing series when inverting a chart with more than one serie. It worked before we upgraded to v3.0 of Highcharts. So the technique of "dynamically" inverting the chart, is to copy the previous charts options, change the inverted option, then creating a new chart with these options.

```
options = jQuery.extend(true, {}, chart.options);
options.chart.inverted = isInverted;
chart.destroy();
chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
```

This worked "nicely" before. But now it only keeps one serie. Tried all sorts of solutions, copying the serie object, and adding each serie to the new object, without luck because the copied object uses pointers.

Any takers ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the reason:
the chart.options object didn't contain the series, just the series object contained them. The series had been added using Chart.addSeries(). Shouldn't this method also make a options.series object?
Anyways, pushed in a new object in the array, got the settings from chart.series, and voila!